# SQLite: Duplicate row n times to the end of a table, but with some altered data?

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, join, common-table-expression

I have a table called 'scenes'...

```
id   created       modified      scene_id
------------------------------------------
1    1999-11-31    2000-01-27    ABCD
2    2000-12-31    2001-01-27    EFGH
3    2001-12-31    2002-01-27    IJKL
4    2002-12-31    2003-01-27    MNOP
5    2003-12-31    2004-01-27    QRST
```

...what I'm trying to do is to duplicate a row (line 2 in this example) at the end of the table n times (4 in this example), but also alter the scene_id to give them unique identifiers.  This is a shortened explanation, but the original is a large table with about 50 columns, and I want to split some of the rows into separate parts, to get something like this:

```
id   created       modified      scene_id
------------------------------------------
1    1999-11-31    2000-01-27    ABCD
2    2000-12-31    2001-01-27    EFGH
3    2001-12-31    2002-01-27    IJKL
4    2002-12-31    2003-01-27    MNOP
5    2003-12-31    2004-01-27    QRST
6    2000-12-31    2001-01-27    EFGH-A
7    2000-12-31    2001-01-27    EFGH-B
8    2000-12-31    2001-01-27    EFGH-C
9    2000-12-31    2001-01-27    EFGH-D
```

I first saved some of the information in a temporary table called 'variables'

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE variables (
    scene_id TEXT, 
    num_files INT,
    scene_index INT
);
INSERT INTO variables VALUES (
  'EFGH',
  4,
  2
);
SELECT * FROM variables;
```

```
scene_id    num_files   scene_index
------------------------------------
EFGH        4           2
```

I also stored line 2 in a table called 'dupedScene'

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE dupedScene AS SELECT * FROM scenes WHERE id = (
    SELECT scene_index FROM variables
);
UPDATE dupedScene 
    SET id = NULL; -- reset id column to trigger auto increment
SELECT * from dupedScene
```

```
id     created       modified      scene_id
-------------------------------------------
null   2000-12-31    2001-01-27    EFGH
```

I then tried various ways to 'loop' INSERT INTO using recursive CTE and JOIN, but I'm struggling to get these things to work together.  I got this far, but I keep getting general errors:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
counter(x) AS (
    SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT x + 1
    FROM counter
    WHERE x < (SELECT num_files FROM variables)
)
INSERT INTO scenes
  SELECT * FROM dupedScene
  JOIN counter ON x
```

Any SQL masters that can help?

Answer (score 0):

The query would be

```
INSERT INTO scenes
WITH RECURSIVE
counter(x) AS (
    SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT x + 1
    FROM counter
    WHERE x < (SELECT num_files FROM variables)
)
  SELECT * FROM dupedScene
  JOIN counter ON x
```

But you have 5 Columns that you try to insert into scenes, but that is easily remeded

see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLbLD5eiRV8gKYc4RrB6o3/0

Comment: I'm getting the very same error when the lines are re-ordered like that.

Comment: then you are doing something wrong https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLbLD5eiRV8gKYc4RrB6o3/1

Comment: Ah, might have been a missing semi-colon at the end.  Very good.  Any idea how I can also add A, B, C, etc, to the 'scene_id' column as well (mentioned above)?

Comment: sure https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLbLD5eiRV8gKYc4RrB6o3/2

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to avoid inserting into the 'id' column, as this is the primary key...I had made it null in the duplicate to get it to auto-increment.  It copies over using with a * (not listing the columns), but I just can't figure out how to combine that with the loop.

Comment: Moving 'INSERT INTO scenes' to the top of the query doesn't seem to make any difference to the query.  It runs with the columns defined in both orders...while the column names get past the errors, it's not getting the result I'm after as it messes up the incremental id column.  The actual table is 50 columns wide and 30,000 rows long, so I'm trying to avoid introducing human error by naming all the columns.

Comment: then you would do something like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLbLD5eiRV8gKYc4RrB6o3/3 i caution always if concurrency is used, to look up the manual, because queies like that can lead to problem with duplicates. also you should take a look at autoincrement https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html which alos would provide a solution.